# What court fees were payable in respect of the case Meads v. Meads?

Tags: court, fees, alberta

Presumably one of the parties had brought the case and (at least initially) had to pay the claim/application fee to the court, whether or not they were later reimbursed. In total, when all was said and done, how much money did the courts receive in respect of this case?

This is perhaps driving toward a larger question, which maybe ought to be posted separately, but I'm not fully convinced that is needed: do courts generally run at a loss, a profit, or breaking even?

Comment: Courts generally run at a loss, although mostly from the criminal side. A very large share of cases end in default judgments or settlements so the low fees average out on the civil side.

Answer (score 1):

Alberta's schedule of court fees is [published here](https://www.alberta.ca/court-fees.aspx). To bring a claim under the Family Law Act at the Court of King's Bench is $50. And each subsequent application is $50. To set a matter for trial would have been $600.

There are no futher reported decisions in relation to this litigation; my best guess is that this was resolved without any futher significant litigation (although there could very well be unreported judgments confirming relatively straightforward support payments or issuing orders on consent of the parties).

Paragraphs 8-10 suggest there were at least two applications in this matter.

Comment: Does this imply a total of $100?